# Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial by Michael Hartl - Lesson 3 Static Pages Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

the system-created page http://localhost:3000/pages/home shows up fine. but when i change the content of the file home.html.erb and reload the page in the browser and view the source code, i see the content from my home.html.erb file gets added under the automatically created content. so basically there are two pages in the source code. anyone knows what causes that?

my application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SampleApp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

my home.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sample App</h1>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your `app/view/layouts/application.html.erb` and `app/view/pages/home.html.erb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `application.html.erb` is fine, but `home.html.erb` is used to include only what's inside `<body>` tag. So, in your case it must contain only the
`<h1>Sample App</h1>
    ...`
part.